Flight Deck Visibility Reference Source

Where does this drawing (T-tail airplane on approach) come from? I have seen it cited before in conversations but without a reference such as an advisory circular or AMC.


Is there a higher-resolution version?  That would let us use a font identifier, which might narrow down the decade or country.  2. Both meters and feet is unusual;  what other diagrams have that?


It actually comes from the "Toren book", that is Synthesis of subsonic airplane design (1976) by Egbert Torenbeek, an engineer and professor of Aerospace Engineering at Delft University of Technology:
On page 92:

This diagram illustrates a proposal to change the regulation about cockpit design, e.g. FAR 25.777: standards must be evolved for this category of aircraft to ensure clear areas of vision during the approach. [...] The angle of view forward and downward must be sufficient to allow the pilot to see the approach and/or touchdown zone lights over a distance equal to the distance covered
in 3 seconds at the landing speed when the aircraft is [...] at a decision height which places the lowest part of the aircraft at a height of 100 feet above the touchdown zone.
You can access a scan of 2nd edition at TU Delft, be patient, the file size is large and the server datarate is limited.

This image has been used once on this stack: Why does the Boeing 787 have fewer cockpit windows?

Also was used in this thread. Nice find!
